# jquery datepicker display issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker

[image: date picker]
<sub>(source: [easycaptures.com](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/661/7740052223.png))</sub>

HTML code

```
<div class="paddingTop30 height30">
    <div class="width100 inline greyText">Lesson Date</div>
    <div class="width110 inline">
        <input type="text" name="dateTimePicker" id="dateTimePicker"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inline {
    float:left
}
```

JS

```
$('#dateTimePicker').datepicker();
```

Display of datepicker is not correct. Where I am going wrong ?
FYI: Create lesson is a jquery dialog

Comment: please share the jquery files(css&JS) which u added

Comment: What happens when you remove the class "inline" from the div with class="width110 inline"? I suspect the float is causing the issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most display problems are due to corrupt or wrong jquery css files. Please ensure you have added the css files that came with jquery.

Hope I helped you.